# Azure DevOps - Is it possible to get the list of the iteration paths in a project?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I have a project that has iteration paths set up like this: Project-Name/sub-project/year/quarter/sprint

I want to get the list of sub-projects in each Project (or a list of all iteration paths and I can clean the data myself). Is this possible using REST API? If not, are there any other ways to achieve this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [classification nodes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/classification-nodes/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0#get-an-iteration) api to get the iteration tree

The following will give you a nested list of iteration with children depth set to 1 (which should contain your sub-projects as the last level. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/classification-nodes/get-classification-nodes?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0#get-the-iteration-tree-with-2-levels-of-children) for an example of the returned data.

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/Fabrikam-Fiber-Git/_apis/wit/classificationnodes/Iterations?api-version=6.0&depth=1
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thank you!